# Call functino/sub in Microsoft Excel Objects -> This Workbook VBE hierarchy

Tags: vba, excel

I had no luck finding a way to call a function which is saved in the ThisWorkbook component of the VBE tree. I tried

```
Dim vbComponentName As String
vbComponentName = "ThisWorkbook"
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim vbcomp As VBComponent
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
For Each vbcomp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
    If vbcomp.Name = vbComponentName Then
        Debug.Print "command: " & wb.Name & "!" & vbcomp.Name & ".Open"
        Application.Run (wb.Name & "!" & vbcomp.Name & ".Open")
    End If
Next
```

which prints:

```
Long Name File_v.18.xlsm!ThisWorkbook.Open
```

But it does not work. It compiles but gives me an error:

```
Cannot run the macro "XYX". 
The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disable.
```

Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your code?

Comment: Two things: 1) Is the procedure a `Sub` or `Function`. 2) Is it labeled `Private`?

Comment: It's a Private Sub as I want to call the built in Open sub. But it can be a public function as I assume I can call it from a Private Sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is with the file's name having spaces, that's why you tried to put those parentheses. I did a similar test and it worked but instead of using parenthese I did it this way:

```
   Application.Run "'" & wb.name & "'" & "!" & vbcomp.name & ".mySub"
```

Comment: Brilliant! This was easy!

Comment: I tried but it appears that I do not have enough feedback. If anybody can accept this for me?

Comment: Oh, ok, i should have clicked on the tick symbol, not the up arrow. Great, thanks @ASH

Comment: @hardish you're welcome, thanks for answering the call :)